# Как из формы передать объект со списком вложенных объектов?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-data-jpa

Я новичок в Thymeleaf и Spring-е. Есть класс `Person`, который содержит поля `Set<Addtess>` и `Set<PhoneNumber>`.

После редактирования необходимо сохранить измененные данные.

Как передать из формы в контроллер объект `Person` c вышеуказанными полями?

Мой контроллер и форма не хотят сохранять `Set`-ы.

**Форма:**

```
<form action="/personData/save" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <input type="text" name="id" th:value="${person.getId()}">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" th:value="${person.getLastName()}"/>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" th:value="${person.getFirstName()}">
    <input type="text" name="patronymic" th:value="${person.getPatronymic()}">
    <p th:each="phone:${person.getPhoneNumbers()}">
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" th:value="${phone.getType()}">
        <input type="text" name="phoneType" th:value="${phone.getNumber()}">
    </p>
    <p th:each="address:${person.getAddresses()}">
        <input type="text" name="houseNumber" th:value="${address.getHouseNumber()}">
        <input type="text" name="street" th:value="${address.getStreet()}">
        <input type="text" name="city" th:value="${address.getZipCode()}">
        <input type="text" name="region" th:value="${address.getCity()}">
        <input type="text" name="country" th:value="${address.getCountry()}">
        <input type="text" name="zipCode" th:value="${address.getZipCode()}">
    </p>
    <p>
    <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
```

---

**Контроллер:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String personSave(@ModelAttribute Person person,
                             Model model) {
        personRepo.save(person);
        model.addAttribute("persons", personRepo.findAll());
        return "main";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте значения используя индекс

```
<p th:each="phone,stat:${person.getPhoneNumbers()}">
    <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[${__stat.index__}].phoneNumber" th:value="${phone.getType()}">
    <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[${__stat.index__}].phoneType" th:value="${phone.getNumber()}">
</p>
```

Comment: выдает ошибку Сould not parse as expression: "phoneNumber[${stat.index}]".

Comment: может быть так подойдет?

Comment: ошибок не выдает, но данные отредактированные данные не сохраняются

Comment: попробуйте так, может быть данные попадут в атрибут `person`. Остальные аттрибуты - `id`, `lastname`, и пр. попадают в атрибут?

Comment: так ошибку выдает org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "phoneNumbers[stat.index].phoneNumber". Да, с простыми полями проблем нет, проблема с коллекциями

Comment: так вроде не должно быть ошибок

Comment: Сначала была ошибка на счет фигурных скобок - заменил их на квадратные. Вот такая ошибка стала появляться: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Cannot call #entrySet() on an IContext implementation. Можете дать ссылку на документацию, где написано  про эти индексы?

Comment: Вот так заработало : <p th:each="phone,stat:${person.getPhoneNumbers()}">
        <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[____${stat.index}____].type" th:value="${phone.getType()}">
        <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[___${stat.index}___].number" th:value="${phone.getNumber()}">
    </p>

Answer (score 0):

Вот так заработало:

```
<p th:each="phone,stat:${person.getPhoneNumbers()}">
        <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[__${stat.index}__].type" th:value="${phone.getType()}">
        <input type="text" th:name="phoneNumbers[__${stat.index}__].number" th:value="${phone.getNumber()}">
    </p>
```